# How feasible is a social order based on the immunity of people to harmful external stimuli?

Tags: society

The idea I have is, based on how well people can see in a certain radiation, they're placed on different levels of the pecking order. The better they can manage the increased levels of radiation, the higher up they are.

Oh yeah. Also, the people at the bottom of the social order would be someone for whom the external stimulus is fatal.

Doesn't necessarily mean exposure to radiation, but to any kind of external stimulus/stimuli.

So, the question is, how feasible is this kind of social order?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, Sphoorthy! This question feels very broad to me. Can you enclose on the topic? How do you plan on determining answer quality?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that questions asking for references to existing material [are likely to be closed as off-topic](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/is-asking-for-examples-on-topic). You might instead ask how believable such a system would be or how well it would work.

Comment: Okay. Will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find many of your answers in a book called "Shades of Grey" written by Jasper Fforde. It happens to be a fantastic book, the premise of which is a society which forms its hierarchy based on what colours a person can see.

The attribute is very testable, assuming that a person would try as hard as possible in the test in order to maximise their status. In this sense your exact position in society can be determined.

An interesting element Jasper Fforde uses a lot is that people would inevitably wish to maximise the position of their children and family in society. As such, poor children with good vision might be married off to children of wealthy people whose vision is not as good as hoped. Essentially wealthy families would perpetuate their status through buying 'good radiation genes' from the poor. A similar situation might arise if genetic engineering or genetic selection is possible in your society.

Comment: Woah. This is an awesome answer and reference. Really makes me feel much more confident about my own idea. Thanks @stu